# CPU request has been approved on google cloud but not showing on the VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-dl-platform

My request of more CPU's has been approved for Google Cloud Compute Engine. When I ssh into my VM on the cloud and do lscpu, I do not see an increased number of CPU's. How do I carry those CPU's into the VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to @john Hanley

You can also use this step by step

1. Open the Google cloud Platform console
2. Open Compute Engine > VM instances
3. Select the VM you need to shut down
4. Open the Virtual Machine and properly shutdown the VM
5. Edit the the VM
6. Locate the CPU platform
7. Adjust your preferred vCPUs to core ratio & Visible core count
8. Click save and verify the VM instance size.

For complete guide you may refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#changing_a_machine_type).

Answer (score 2):

Changing a CPU quota does not change the number of CPUs a VM has. You will need to shutdown the VM and edit its configuration to select a different instance size.